# Entity Framework: multiple DB having the same schema

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext, multiple-databases

I have just created an ASP.NET MVC 4 & WebAPI project. After that I have added `.edmx` data source to project.

I have multiple databases with the same schema. Dynamically I want to replace connection string using default constructor provided in EF.

But in `Model1.Designer.cs`, every time I get error like "Member with same signature already declared".

I'm unable to solve this problem.

Comment: Doesn't VS generate a context with a constructor that takes a string parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works! All you need to change is the connection string.

And I have just tested it in order to satisfy my own curiosity.

Here are the steps that I took:

1. Take an existing database and create a model for it.
2. Create a new empty database.
3. In *SQL Management Studio* right click the first database -> Tasks -> Export Data. Export all it's data to the newly created database.
4. Remove some records from the second database.
5. Write this code:

   ```
   TMS_MiscEntities db = new TMS_MiscEntities();
   TMS_MiscEntities dbCopy = new TMS_MiscEntities();
   dbCopy.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString.Replace("initial catalog=TMS_Misc", "initial catalog=TMS_Misc_new");

   Response.Write(string.Format("DB 1 records: {0}<br/>", db.ZipCodes.Count()));
   Response.Write(string.Format("DB 2 records: {0}<br/>", dbCopy.ZipCodes.Count()));
   ```
6. Check results:

   ```
   DB 1 records: 869164
   DB 2 records: 868709
   ```
7. Conclude that it works :)

This is how my connection string looks:

```
<add name="TMS_MiscEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DbModel.csdl|res://*/DbModel.ssdl|res://*/DbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ws2008;initial catalog=TMS_Misc;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: i will surely test it by tomorrow.  if it doesnt work i ll let u know my scenario....  thanks for the reply.

Comment: Not working. I'm using EF6. dbCopy.Database.Connection.ConnectionString.....
I'm unable to resolve .Database. it shows error in there.

Comment: What errors? Also are you sure the database schema is actually the same? Can you try exporting an existing database to a newly created one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266129/how-to-change-database-dynamically-havning-same-schema-dynamically-using-entity

Comment: I see. That error doesn't seem related to using multiple dbs. It's just EF.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3. I have added a constructor to my DbContext that takes a string parameter. This string can be the name of the connection stored in your App.config or a full connection string. Something like this:

```
public partial class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

   // DbSets, OnModelCreating, etc 
}
```

In my case, I manage a multi-tenant application and I use a ContextFactory to build the proper connection string and return my initialized context.

```
public class ContextFactory
{
    public MyDbContext GetContext()
    {
        string connectionString;
        // do some stuff here
        return new MyDbContext(connectionString);
    }
}
```