# multiple database connection with entity framework 6

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, edmx

I have asp. net mvc 4 web api application. 
in sql server, i have one Database named clientDBManager which has different clients with one  connection string per client...

eg.

clientDBManager has, 
1) client name : steve, 
connectionString : sql connection string which points to steve's individual db named clientDBSteve

2) client name : john, 
connectionString : sql connection string which points to john's individual  db named clientDBJohn

and so on....

Scenario is,  IN SQL server i have
one clientDBManager which has it own one or two tables. 
while on other side DBs like clientDBSteve and clientDBJohn have
similar no of tables  around 50tables(having same schema)...

i want to add .edmx file to project and want to use different clients dbs (having same schema)  in just one go dynamically...

is it possible?

if not what should i do????

with clientDBManager i will identify which user is logged in.
if Steve is logged in then clientDBSteve should be used for data manipulation.

if john is logged in then clientDBJohn should be used for data manipulation.

this should be done dynamically....

pls help how to do it.....

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/a/27256440/4304188

Comment: suggested way is not working...

Comment: can you pls help me further?

Comment: when i write dbCopy. Database..... in c# it doesnt not resolve   .Database keyword anyhow. which namespace is used to resolve .Database keyword?????u